# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///Resources/StudentImages/195/image_picker1079633126869562649.jpg

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

i am show data through calling api but i can't set image because below error show

Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///Resources/StudentImages/195/image_picker1079633126869562649.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an Image.network and the url you are using is from a local file.